# Shotgun mic orientation inside windshield

Tags: shotgun, microphone, windshield

Maybe this is a silly question, but here it goes.

When I put my shotgun mic (416) in the windshield, I don't know if I should orient the interference gaps horizontally or vertically.

¿Does the mic orientation (twisting it along his axis) affects the sound in any way?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't affect it, but I just have a habit of having clipped in horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes no difference...at least not one that I've ever noticed.

Comment: Agreed, no difference noticed using my MKH 60 with a Rycote windshield kit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I always position the gaps facing the sides of the zeppelin 'cause I'm convinced it's better to have both grills as free as possible instead of having one of 'em possibly shadowed by the baseplate of the shockmount!

When it comes to these things, especially since it doesn't really take any extra time to turn the mic perhaps an extra 90 degrees, I prefer to be safe over mildly sorry :-)

Comment: Interesting. Actually I do the same almost by instinct.